# How to migrate a VMWare Fusion OS to an actual partition?

Tags: linux, freebsd, vmware-fusion, operating-system

As the title says. How can I migrate a VMWare Fusion OS to run on bare metal hardware?

Answer (score 3):

Hm, you can boot there from a LiveCD and make a disk image, then tranfer it to your host computer, and write the image where you need :)

I believe there will be some booting problems, so don't forget to configure your loader.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare has guidance on doing a V2P (Virtual to Physical) migration here: http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of your virtual disk to a place available to you when you boot on the bare metal with the restoration software.

The procedure is identical to what should be done when migrating between two physical pieces of hardware.